# Why can't I call a PL/pgSQL function from a pgAdmin pgScript?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

Our PostgreSQL database contains a function written in PL/pgSQL. I can run it just fine from an SQL query window like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT sg_copy_form(414, 2621, 1, 1035);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

However if I run exactly the same SQL above as a pgScript (for example, click the *Execute pgScript* button in pgAdmin instead of *Execute query*) then I get the following error:

```
[QUERY    ] BEGIN TRANSACTION
[WARNING  ] SELECT sg_copy_form(414, 2621, 1, 1035)
        ERROR:  function sg_copy_form(integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
        LINE 1: SELECT sg_copy_form(414, 2621, 1, 1035)
                       ^
        HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[QUERY    ] ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Why is this? Is it possible to call a PL/pgSQL function from a pgScript?

If relevant: I'm trying this on PostgreSQL 8.3.14 with pgAdmin III 1.12.2.

---

**EDIT:** I tried fully-qualifying the name of the function as suggested by Eelke, like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT db_dev.public.sg_copy_form(414, 2621, 1, 1035);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

It still works correctly when run as a normal SQL query, but now I get a *different* error message when I run it as a pgScript:

```
[QUERY    ] BEGIN TRANSACTION
[WARNING  ] SELECT db_dev.public.sg_copy_form(414, 2621, 1, 1035)
        ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: db_dev.public.sg_copy_form
[QUERY    ] ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: This means, that the pgScript is executed within the context of another database.

Comment: A statement like this: `SELECT mydb.myschema.some_func(..);` can never work. As the error message says: cross-database references are not implemented. You cannot prefix the database-name. You must be mistaken in your edit.

Comment: The text of the edit above is correct. It turns out that a likely bug in pgAdmin (see comments in answer below) means it executes the pgScript on the wrong database. So when executing the code above as SQL the prefix matches the database name and thus causes no problems; when executing the code as pgScript it runs on a different database and so the prefix doesn't match and triggers the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you double-check that you have the same environment in both cases? Please check

- same database,
- same user,
- same search_path

The problem is most probably that some settings in pgadmin3 are different and you just don't "see" the function.

**Edit**

You can compare the settings like this:

Execute this as plain SQL (i.e. only "Execute"):

```
select current_database(), current_user, current_setting('search_path');
```

Execute this as pgScript:

```
declare @foo{ @db, @usr, @p };
set @foo = select current_database(), current_user, current_setting('search_path');
print @foo;
```

**End Edit**

BTW: as the error message comes from the server, this would happen with functions written in *any* language (e.g. SQL, pljava), not just PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely same database, user and search_path because the only difference is which button I press in pgAdmin: _Execute query_ or _Execute pgScript_

Comment: Could you try setting the search path explicitly or fully qualify the function name? I know it shouldn't be needed but pgAdmin might be doing something weird (as in contain a bug).

Comment: I've tried setting the search path with `SET search_path TO public;` and it makes no difference. However when I fully quality the function name then I do get a _different_ error message — see my edit above!

Comment: I'm not sure pgscript can handle stored procedures.

Comment: @fluca1978: The _server_ does not distinguish between its own functions and user defined functions. The error message is a server message. So pgAdmin is out unless it does something _very_ magically.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because your example code did help me find the problem: it appears to be a bug in pgAdmin. The value returned by `current_database()` changes when run as SQL versus when run as pgScript — even though I'm running it in the same pgAdmin window. To be specific, the pgScript is running on the wrong database because `current_database()` returns a different value to the database name shown in the title bar on the window. I'll report it as a likely bug to the pgadmin-support mailing list.

Comment: Here's my bug report: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgadmin-support/2012-02/msg00151.php